# Moved Category By Mistake and Now URL key has changed

Tags: magento

I wanted to move a category called "trinkets" before one called "widgets". Instead, it somehow ended up inside of "widgets." When I moved it back out, the url key was changed to "trinkets-1". How do I get it back to "trinkets"?

Answer (score 2):

Here is something I found - http://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-administration/664-fixing-url-rewrites-with-magento

Quoted from the above website:

> Sometimes when you make changes to your products, or enable a certain extension, Magento might start to rewrite all your URLs to include a suffix "-1" or some other number. Within the URL Rewrites, Magento differentiates between System URLs and Custom URLs. If the System URLs are broken like this, you should not fix this by adding new Custom URLs.
>
> Instead, open up phpMyAdmin, create a backup of your Magento database, and flush the Magento table core_url_rewrite (so that it becomes totally empty). Immediately afterwards, refresh the Catalog Url Rewrites under Index Management. This will regenerate all System URLs.

If you are comfortable to take a backup and try removing all the records from the above table (obviously preceded by any table pre-fixes), it sounds like a quick fix.

Comment: Just a caution to the wind with this solution, it will remove all of your existing redirects, so for example if you've renamed product URLs and categories, these will be removed too. Therefore any sites linking to old URLs, will now get a 404. If you want to keep them you'll need to export before wiping, and then import with some careful SQL :)

Answer (score 1):

When you rename a category an URL Rewrite Rule is generated so you don't loose the traffic that is incoming on the original category url (see *Catalog -> Url Rewrite Management*, search for *Request Path*: trinkets).

Now, when you move it back it checks if the URL Key "trinkets" is already used (which is, because a redirect was generated).

Delete from *URL Rewrite Rules* the records matching "trinkets" and modift the url key (edit category). Also, when you modify the URL key for the category, make sure the checkbox for " *Create Permanent Redirect for old URL*" is unchecked.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It isn't as problematic as one might think.
In addition you can add more generic rewrites to your .htaccess file to reduce the amount of individual per file redirects in magentos core_rewrite table.